# Can I set HighChart startOnTick/EndOnTick dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

Is there a way how to change those once chart is created?

I'm trying to set startOnTick/endOnTick properties:

```
function SetNewExtremes()
{
    chart.yAxis[0].endOnTick = false;
    chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(-150,102);
    //chart.redraw();
}
```

However this option seems to be ignored once the chart is created.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4ad7nf5k/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set properties with a function. There is no specific function for `endOnTick`, so you need to use [`update`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update). Like this:

```
function SetNewExtremes()
{
  chart.update({yAxis: {endOnTick: false}},false); //setting redraw to false so we don't redraw twice
  chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(-150,102);
}
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/4ad7nf5k/2/